# AdMob - Example Ads work, my own Interstitial doesn't

Tags: android, interstitial, admob, mobile-development

I am currently making an app with interstitial ads. I have setup everything, but when I tested the ads (in test mode) I got nothing even after waiting for a week.

Now, the thing is, that Google's provided Test Ads (in their documentation) work perfectly fine. So my code has to be right as well. So I have to have misconfigured something...

The thing is, I don't know what. I have added my payment options, gotten an "your account is activated" email, used the right id and my ad is active. Any advice?

PS: I have got an Email from Google AdWords which wants me to call Google in order to complete the AdWord Setup, but that hasn't anything to do with AdMob, now has it?

Comment: So your interstitials work only with the test ad id, or do I get you wrong?

Comment: Yes. If I use my own interstitial id, it doesn't work. Not even in test mode.

Comment: Could you test it on a real device with your own id?
Make sure you use app id and ad unit id correctly otherwise

Comment: I have tested it on a real device and the ad unit id is also correctly. I don't use the app id tough, but it doesn't seem to be needed and all tutorials which I followed, neglected the app id.